# Sending email fails with microsoft.office.interop

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I posted my question in another forum and they told me that's a technical problem .

I have problem when sending email via a vb.net application .sometimes the mail is sent perfectly and in some cases its sent like encoded text :

I use that code to send :

```
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application()
Dim email As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
email.Recipients.Add(row.ToString)
email.Subject = "subjecttext" 
email.Body = "bodytext" 

DirectCast(email,Outlook.MailItem).Send()
```

and the mail is sent like that

> MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0010_01CEF013.5B447120"
>   X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 15.0
>   Thread-Index: Ac7wCvGXqJZh0WA1RT29BR1tIH9fLA==
>   Content-Language: fr

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

> Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset="iso-8859-1"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

And if i want to send an attachment in my xp machine with outlook 2007 it works but in a window machine with outlook 2010 it doesnt work.

Hope my explanation is clear

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do, but try to just use `email.Send()` instead of doing another `DirectCast()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and it drove me crazy. The issue for me was a new line character (ascii 10) in the subject of the email. Apparently multi-line subjects are not dealt with properly. I found the suggestion [here](https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/95695-emails-configured-as-html-but-sent-as-plain-text/)